# JNI AttachThead/DetachThread performance?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, java-native-interface

I'm using tool that performs computation in worker threads (not sure how it manages them) and uses visitor design pattern so my visitor function is executed with calculated data:

```
void func_visitor(void *context, int calculated_value)
{
  vm->AttachCurrentThread(&(env->jni_env), NULL);

  // save calculated_value

  vm->DetachCurrentThread(); 
}

void perform_long_calculation()
{
    exec_tool(context, &func_visitor);
}
```

Then i have to save the data in the java list. I have to attach thread in visitor, add calculated data in the list and then detach thread. Is it much faster to save calculated data somewhere in global list skipping attach/detach and add all the data after visitor is executed.

Comment: Depends on your system.  Some VMs may cache the mapped native thread, so that not much happens in the attach.  Overall, you'll want to reduce the number of JNI crossings; if you can skip the JNI until the very end, you'll have better performance.

Comment: Well, that's not obvious that it will be faster as i will have to save data somewhere instead of java result array and collect it after all visitor invocations will be done. So the question is how expensive are attach/detach calls?

Comment: It's not the attach/detach itself, it's the crossing from native space into JVM space.  Not a big deal for a few, but for a few million, the crossing costs can become significant.  I'd recommend doing the simplest, clearest, most correct thing first, then worry about making it faster if it proves to be too slow.